# error creating bean with name employeeController. injection of autowired dependencies failed. could not autowire fields

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

**Error From Console**

```
 SEVERE: Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ram.service.EmployeeService com.ram.controller.EmployeeController.employeeService; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ram.dao.EmployeeDao com.ram.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.employeeDao;
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
```

**EmployeeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Qualifier(value="employeeService")
    public void setEmployeeService(EmployeeService employeeService){
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listEmployee(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        model.addAttribute("listEmployee", employeeService.listEmployee());
        return "employee";
    }
```

Comment: The problem is caused by the `employeeService` bean which the instantiation by Spring fails as there is not  a declared bean with the `EmployeeDao` class. You should show the `EmployeeService` and the `EmployeeDao` class and also probably the used Spring configuration.

Comment: Probably you're missing @Component annotation in EmployeeService and EmployeeDao in order to let Spring know about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is most imporatant from the log. Unfortunately, the log is incomplete, so it's unclear which property of `EmployeeDao` is missing:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
```

What fields are you mapping into `EmployeeDao`? Because one of those cannot be found, perhaps not marked with `@Component`?

Comment: i have used @Repository for employeeDaoImpl

Comment: No, not on `EmployeeDaoImpl`... on anything that `EmployeeDaoImpl` autowires. What does it require? Can you add the class to your question?